# SyntaxError, cannot use import statement outside a module, occurs even with "type":"module" in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules

I am trying to use ES6 Modules to import Express. Although I added `"type":"module"` in my package.json. The error, `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, still occurs. I am expecting an answer which does not require to convert into a .ejs extension since wanting to know what's wrong in my code rather than taking an alternative. Note: `package.json` & `server.js` are in the same directory.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Server.js

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('hello world');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on localhost: ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: What Node.JS version do you have?

Comment: It's v12.14.0. I realized that only Node version at least 13.2.0+ works with ES6 Modules. Once I updated to the the latest version, everything works perfectly. Thank you for your reminder. @Take-Some-Bytes